# Spring Data JPA not saving to database when using Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring Boot application using JPA that has 1 PostgreSQL database. And I am using Spring Batch. The scenario is I am reading a file and writing data to the PostgreSQL database. The program works with PostgreSQL when it is creating meta-data tables used by Spring Batch in the database. But what I need is Spring Boot not to create meta-data tables and use in-memory Map-based job repository by Spring Batch. I don't want to create meta-data tables in the database at all. Need to just execute in-memory Map-based. I tried many answers but none of them worked. And I see,

> MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean is deprecated

Here is my `BatchConfiguration.java` class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private @Autowired JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private @Autowired StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private @Autowired UserItemReader userItemReader;
    private @Autowired UserItemProcessor userItemProcessor;
    private @Autowired UserItemWriter userItemWriter;

    @Bean
    public Step importUsersStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("STEP-01")
                .<User, User>chunk(10)
                .reader(userItemReader)
                .processor(userItemProcessor)
                .writer(userItemWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUsersJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB-IMPORT")
                .flow(importUsersStep())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

`Repository.java` class,

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

And in `UserItemWriter.java` in `write` method I am calling `userRepository.saveAll();`

So how can I make this to work with in-memory Map-based and also since I am using Spring Data JPA to save the user to the database so the save should also work without any issue because when I am trying some approaches I saw nothing committed to PostgreSQL and I think even the user data also committed to in-memory Map. So anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which transaction manager are you using? By default, Spring Batch uses a `DataSourceTransactionManager` if you provide a datasource in your context. But if you use JPA, you need to configure Spring Batch to use a `JpaTransactionManager` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solve this problem by defining multiple datasources. One in memory datasource for Spring Batch Metadatas and another or more datasources for jobs depending on configuration.

```
# for spring batch metadata
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

# for jobs
job.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
job.datasource.username=user
job.datasource.password=password
```

We create datasource manually like

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties mysqlDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
```

and another one.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.package.name",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "postgresTransactionManager")
public class PostgresDataConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("postgres.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties postgresDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "postgresEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean postgresEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(postgresDataSource())
                .packages("com.bimurto.multipledatasource.postgres")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "postgresTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager postgresTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("postgresEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(entityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }
}
```

This allows to repositories use another datasource than the default one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and your time.

Comment: Did you add `@Transactional("postgresTransactionManager")` to your methods? Because I have the same case, even if I add H2 DB the transaction is managed by spring-batch, but the job data source was primary.

Answer (score 1):

`MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` was only recommended for testing and development purposes, not for production use, it has a number of issues, that's why it was deprecated.

Spring Batch will try to use the `DataSource` from your `ApplicationContext` if you
have one. If you don't want Spring Batch to use it to store its state, you could use a `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` with an embedded database. The easiest way to do so, is to define a `BatchConfigurer` bean:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer configurer() {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource());
}

public DataSource dataSource(){
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
            .build();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code. But it's not working it's not saving data to database may be it's saving to in-memory database. Do I need to configure anything with `JobRepositoryFactoryBean `. I am sorry for my lack of knowledge in this as I am new to this. So kindly can you help me?

Comment: The `DefaultBatchConfigurer` will configue a `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` with the passed dataSource. You should have your own PostgreSQL datasource defined as a bean (which will be used by your JPA repositories)

Comment: I am currently defining all things in the `properties` file. Including `datasource url` for `PostgreSQL`. Ho can I configure that to work on this?